# PHP session returns NULL but session has been created

Tags: php, session, lamp, web-development-server

I assume this is a problem with the permissions on /tmp but I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm using PHP to create a register and login page; I can see that when a user logs in the session data is passed to the /tmp folder, however when they're redirected to home/index page the session data returns NULL.

I've used the below to verify the the correct path has permissions:

```
<?php

    var_dump($_SESSION);
    if (!is_writable(session_save_path()))
    {
            echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is writable for PHP!'; 
    }

?>
```

And I end up with:

```
NULL Session path "/var/lib/php/sessions" is writable for PHP!
```

Checking the folder, I can see the session data saved to /tmp so it's definitely writable.

So my best guess is that start_session() has permission to write to /tmp but doesn't have the permission to read? But that doesn't make any sense to me.

checking the permissions in the var/lib/php/sessions I get (an example):

```
drwx-wx-wt 2 root root 151552 Dec 22 05:09
```

Would changing the permissions on the folder to:

```
-rw-rw-rw-
```

create any security or other functionality issues?

Comment: please start session using `session_start()` before using any S_SESSION variables

Comment: session.auto_start() is set.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will resolve your problem

> sudo chmod -R 700 /var/lib/php/

and then

> sudo chown -R www-data /var/lib/php/

Comment: ... unless `session.auto_start` is set

Comment: It is, Hence why I'm assuming it's a permissions problem.

Comment: I think this will resolve your problem
**sudo chmod -R 700 /var/lib/php/**
and then 
**sudo chown -R www-data /var/lib/php/**

Comment: It's working now, but won't this allow site users to execute code?

Comment: I don't think you will face such an Issue.